# Unsure what is shifting page across slightly

Tags: html, css

Please take a look here:
http://woddles.co.nz/drillco/

If you switch between the Homepage and the Projects page, you will notice the Page shifts slightly to the left. I'm unsure what attribute is causing this to happen, as the Homepage and About Us page are fine.

I'm sure this is probably a bug with using a specific attribute incorrectly, but I could never work it out.

Comment: Please post your code. How can we help if you don't show us the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but if I was to link the code, I would be linking all of the html and css as I wasn't sure what exactly on the page was causing the issue. (this is why I linked the website itself)

Comment: Yes, but then what happens when you fix the site? This question becomes useless.

Comment: If you can show me a way to 'save' an older state of the website so it can be used to show the problem+solution for my question, I am more than happy to. I suppose I could upload it to a different directory on my website, but there is no guarantee it will stay there forever.

Comment: Post the (relevant) code on this site. You know the problem now, but in the future, narrow it down and post an example of the problem.

Comment: Ah ok, I will do that now. (please let me know if I need to change anything else, should be done fairly quickly)

EDIT: I don't really want to keep replying through comments as I feel I am just spamming. The only relevant code I can add into my post above, is what Fabrício Matté posted earlier. Is it best if I just summarise what my issue was (in my original post) and direct users to his post?

Comment: Well, you can use my demo's code if you feel like. This simplified code (with commented out solution) illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/yL6SM/4/

Comment: Last question, I am required to post code with a jsfiddle link, should I just include all html/css/js from your jsfiddle into the above post or? Sorry fairly new to stackoverflow unsure how things work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the scrollbar appearing.

If it really bothers you, you can have the scrollbar always visible:

```
html {
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yL6SM/3/show/)

However, in my humble opinion, it is a very natural behavior and nearly unnoticeable. I wouldn't recommend using these hacks.

Comment: I realise now that it was probably an almost-silly question because I didn't think about the scrollbar till it was mentioned. But this fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine here but it maybe the scrollbar on smaller screens. Does one page have a scrollbar and the other doesn't on the screen your using?

You could try CSS to force a scrollbar on every page.

```
html { height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px; }
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: How's this not an answer?

Comment: Okay, now you edited it. (removed -1)